# Запуск react-native приложение на android

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

При запуске приложения на устройстве выбивает ошибки

```
API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.
API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'.
API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'.
```

[image: Настройки]

Answer (score 0):

Методы, которые вы используете устарели. В тексте "ошибки" написано, что на что вам надо заменить. Плюс рекомендую вам ознакомится с последней версией документации.

Больше подробностей можно найти здесь 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470044/warning-api-variant-getjavacompile-is-obsolete-and-has-been-replaced-with

Comment: Это понятно, не совсем понимаю как обновить

Comment: Добавил ссылку на детальный разбор вашей ситуации